# терминал не видит переменные среды

Tags: консоль, path

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться...

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Flutter 3.7.7

В директории разрешения есть и на запись и на чтение[image: PATH]

Прописал постоянные переменные среды к папке bin, при команде flutter doctor  пишет что нет такой команды, так как не подтягивает путь..

Comment: так в какой папке бинарник находится?

Comment: /Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin

Comment: в папке flutter

Comment: ну так где  - в /Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin или в папке flutter ?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: в папке bin находится

Comment: нормально можешь ответить - полный путь папки какой?

Comment: я же выше написал ..теперь попробовал переместить  /Users/andryu/Documents/flutter/bin

Comment: пробовали запускать через полный путь ? `./Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin/flutter doctor`

Comment: iMac-Andryu:andryu andryu$ cd /Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin
iMac-Andryu:~ andryu$ flutter doctor
-bash: flutter: command not found
iMac-Andryu:~ andryu$ cd /Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin/flutter doctor
-bash: cd: /Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin/flutter: Not a directory

Comment: А если сразу добавить в путь

iMac-Andryu:~ andryu$ export PATH="$PATH:/Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin"
iMac-Andryu:~ andryu$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G14042 darwin-x64,
    locale ru-UA)

Comment: тогда сохраняет как временную ссылку  и после закрытия терминала уже не работает

Comment: у маков же zsh ? вот так и запишите в файл инициализации переменную PATH выполнив команду: `echo "PATH=$PATH:/Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin" >> $HOME/.zshrc` что добавит в конец файла `~/.zshrc` указанную строчку, после чего перезапустите терминал чтобы изменения вступили в силу.

Comment: всем спасибо, переключил на другой терминал zsh  тогда работает.....

Comment: для баш выполни: `echo "PATH=$PATH:/Volumes/BOX/flutter/bin" >> $HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: посе перезагрузки  не работает....